# Breeze metadata from json-schema

Tags: metadata, breeze, jsonschema

### scenario

We are evaluating breeze to adopt for our [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) mobile apps specifically for its offline caching capabilities. These apps will be consuming REST APIs powered by rails.

There currently exists functionality to generate [json-schema](http://json-schema.org) from the ActiveRecord meta data through [json_schema_builder](https://github.com/salesking/json_schema_builder) and [work is underway to dynamically expose](https://github.com/salesking/json_schema_builder/issues/2) a real-time schema definition. If anyone is keen to get involved please make your intentions known on the github issue since that is not the topic of this conversation.

### breeze meta-data and json-schema

Overjoyed to find a page titled [Meta Schema](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-schema), impressed that breeze adopted json-schema to represent their meta-data. Equally disappointed to realize json-schema is only used to describe their own schema definition similar to the way [meta schemas](http://json-schema.org/schema) are used for describing json-schema itself.

### json-schema 2 breeze meta-data

Lets not get into a debate on why we have json-schema defining yet another meta-data definition nor how valuable it would've been to have these efforts it took to accomplish this funneled into getting json-schema if it was found to be inadequate. Instead all I am searching to find is a way to turn existing json-schema into something breeze.js can understand. Google does not produce more on the topic, that I can find anyway, and the breeze project suggests we take it up here.

The documentation explains a way of [loading meta-data from script](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/load-metadata-script) by capturing the metadata from what I can only assume to be [MC-CSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541474.aspx) Microsofts contribution to yet another standard defining the same.

Aside from doing it [by hand](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-hand-depth) and defeating the purpose of having these resources at our disposal, has anyone tried or know of ways to:

- turn json-schema into breeze meta-data
- perhaps any support for ActiveRecord reflections
- at the very least something to query postgresql for the information

Feel free to correct me if you feel I am mistaken and I apologise in advance for any perceived audacities as it is not my intention to offend or annoy you. Please excuse me if I don't further entertain any complaints. I do however welcome any wisdom, insights and intellectual discourse on this topic and do very much appreciate your valuable time and input.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your dilemma. I keep looking at *json-schema* in hopes that Breeze could join it as a standard. It just doesn't carry the information Breeze needs to manage data on the client.

The *json-schema* does carry much of the schema data that a Breeze client needs. While it might be inadequate on its own, it should give you a head start in writing Breeze metadata by hand.

Some glorious day I imagine a scenario such as this:

- A JavaScript *breeze-metadata-builder* module that can combine metadata information feeds from multiple sources
- A JSON configuration file that identifies those sources

  - One source is a json-schema feed
  - Another source returns hand-written "customizations" that fill-in-the-blanks from a Breeze metadata perspective
- The *breeze-metadata-builder* merges the two sources into a single, Breeze metadata-format feed.
- Run this process in node as a Grunt task, outputting a json or JavaScript file
- Client on launch imports this metadata into a `MetadataStore`

Who is going to write it and share it with the community? How about you @nicki?  I'll happily lend a hand.

Comment: Alas, sounds like fun but I am already spread very thin as is, have you discussed the json-schema shortcomings with the json-schema team on github? Since it is a work in progress it can benefit from your experience/expertise and if it is to be useful at all then it should be complete, do you agree? On your narratives, I agree with all except the generate with grunt import to client. Why can't this be dynamic? I am dealing with similar mind bends with the json-schema from ActiveRecord where the mindset seems to be that this should be static. I don't see why?!?

Comment: No particular reason. They tend to be static in my experience but that doesn't count for much. It's a pipeline anyway so you'd be free to insert whatever and head in a different direction as the spirit moves you.